# logic to see if board game pieces have been captured (go)

Tags: javascript

im developing an online version of the board game go, a japanese game which players take it in turns to place their stone on the grid. When one players stones are surrounded by their opponents, they are destroyed.

This is the logic i cant get my head around how i would program. So far ive made the 2 player grid where all the stones placment are stored in an array. I will include a picture which will make it much clearer here [image: go]

So as you can see, the grid shows that black has 2 white stones surrounded in which case they should be destoryed, note that it can be any number of surrounded stones but in this case its 2.

To the right you can also see the array of stones which i will use to check if a player has been surrounded. I tried to make some pysudo code but it was becoming a mess and way over complicated, is this task really that complicated? any adivice or logic behind how i would do this would be appriated so if anyone online has done something similar that would be good too. Im not even sure making an array like i have done is the best way in the end so if theres a better way please let me know

Comment: You will need to narrow your question to something more specific than "*how to I program my game*". As it stands, the question is way to broad.

Comment: i was more after the logic/ pseudo code for how a function would perform instead of someone to code my whole game

Comment: You might start with moving the pieces around the board, then stopping them from overlapping, then work out some logic for adjacency, then surrounding (forming polygons). Then you can work out if a piece is surrounded or not. Algorithms for all that have been around for some time, have a go and see what you come up with.

Comment: yes i can move peices around and if a place is occupied, they wont overlap. ill try and find something on forming polygons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a different data model--essentially a two-dimensional array, holding values of 0, +1, and -1, for empty, black, and white respectively. For purposes of your algorithm, maintain a parallel array of booleans for "has liberty".

Your algorithm will need to scan the board multiple times. Prior to the scan, set the "has liberty" flag for a location to false if and only if the location is occupied. On each scan, find all the cells with "has liberty" of true and mark the cell to the left, right, top, and bottom as "has liberty"; if the location is occupied, restrict this marking to adjacent locations of the same color. When nothing changes on the board after a scan, you are done. At that point, all the stones with "has liberty" remaining false are captured and should be removed.

This is a simple, inefficient algorithm. Go engines such as GNU go have much more sophisticated algorithms that involve keeping track of "chains" or "groups" of connected stones, with their number of liberties, and then update those as stones are played. If you are planning to write a go-playing program, you will be doing this calculation thousands or millions of times as you read out different sequences, so that kind of optimization will become crucial.

Note that you will need to do special casing for the situation known as "ko" and similar situations where a stone is played in a seemingly "captured" position but survives because it itself takes other stones. . If you simply place the stone taking the ko on the board, and run the above algorithm, then both the stone being taken and the stone just played will be considered to be captured, which is wrong. Therefore, you need a board-level variable for most recent stone, and consider that stone to always be in the "has liberty" state, with appropriate logic to handle illegal moves.

Comment: thanks, answer like this was exacly what i was after, i will note this down

Answer (score 3):

A general rough outline for the algorithm:

1. Determine all the spots adjacent to your white pieces (let's use white here for clarity):

   - create two buckets (arrays): white pieces to check, adjacent spots
   - take any white piece, put it into the white-pieces bucket
   - for all the white pieces in your white-pieces bucket, determine their adjacent spots (up, down, left, right)

     - if there's *no white piece* on that spot, put the spot into the adjacent-spots bucket
     - if there's a white piece on that spot, put it into the white-pieces bucket
     - repeat this process until your white-pieces bucket is empty (you have found all the white pieces in a group)
   - (make sure you deduplicate your buckets in the process so you're not running around in circles)
2. Check whether all of the adjacent spots are covered in black pieces.

There's a ton of optimisation that can be done that would make this algorithm much more complicated, and a professional Go program *is* much more complex than this, but it gets you started.

Comment: thanks, answer like this was exacly what i was after, i will note this down